# Cannot redirect to another website on Laravel Show Method

Tags: php, laravel

Recently i just studied creating web apps from this https://www.udemy.com/course/projects-in-laravel-learn-laravel-building-10-projects/ on section Business Listings

i got a problem when i try to access the website from Show Method (showlisting.blade.php).

on this tag:

```
<li class="list-group-item">Website: <a href="{{ $listing->website }}" target="_blank">{{ $listing->website }}</a></li>
```

Expected result must be the url:

```
www.google.com
```

But the actual result is

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/listings/www.google.com
```

i try to add url method on href, like this:

```
<li class="list-group-item">Website: <a href="{{ url($listing->website) }}" target="_blank">{{ $listing->website }}</a></li>
```

the result is much better than before but i need to remove the main route

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/www.google.com
```

Please advise how to remove the main url so it will be display the actual URL like example

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the protocol to thee URL like this:

```
<li class="list-group-item">Website: <a href="http://{{ url($listing->website) }}" target="_blank">{{ $listing->website }}</a></li>
```

this is a generic solution maybe template engine have an absolute URL template function.

Comment: Wow, you save my problem, thank you for the solution, case closed